# Concourse tasks that check uname on different images

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

From the [Stark Concourse tutorial](https://github.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial#01---hello-world-task)

The following task will run the `uname` command with the `-a` switch on a `docker-image` tagged `"14.04"`:

```
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: ubuntu, tag: "14.04"}

run:
  path: uname
  args: [-a]
```

Result:

```
fly -t tutorial e -c task_ubuntu_uname.yml
executing build 10
initializing
running uname -a
Linux a0c3f38b-7dd3-4a8f-7b3e-e56ce2bf05e9 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
succeeded
```

I'm curious why changing the tag doesn't change the version of Ubuntu:

```
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: ubuntu, tag: "16.04"}

run:
  path: uname
  args: [-a]
```

Result:

```
fly -t tutorial e -c task_ubuntu_16_uname.yml
executing build 9
initializing
running uname -a
Linux 58069086-7a27-43f8-71ff-374bcaef0c6d 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
succeeded
```

I see that the guids are different but I would expect the versions to be different too. Why isn't the version 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uname will get the version information of the host's kernel of the machine you're running on - this is not namespaced - so the container you're running isn't going to show.

if you are on an ubuntu host, and run `docker run --rm -it centos uname -a`, it will also still show the ubuntu kernel results.